# Share internet connection from a PC to an iPhone through the USB cable

Tags: iphone, usb, windows, pc, network

In the office where I'm working now, my network carrier has very poor reception, so my iPhone 4 cannot access the internet reliably.
I have a pc running Windows XP SP3 that is connected to internet through LAN, and it does not have a wi-fi card.
Is it possibile to share the PC connectivity to the iPhone through the USB cable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works well for iOS 10 and macOS 10.12:

- [Can I share my iMac's internet to iPhone or iPad over USB?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb)?

You're not the first to ask this question. [Searching with Google shows](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=share+pc+internet+with+iphone+via+usb&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) that it's been discussed [here](http://applefanatic.org/ipod/sharing-desktop-internet-iphone-pod-through-usb-t68285.html) and [here](http://applefanatic.org/ipod/sharing-desktop-internet-iphone-pod-through-usb-t68285.html).

Unfortunately, iOS 9 and earlier do not support what you're describing.

You mention that you don't have a wireless card but perhaps you can share your internet connection wirelessly, through an Ad-Hoc network. I think that's the best way to go, honestly.

This doesn't work for internet:

> [PC] --->--(USB)--->--> [iOS Device]

But this probably would, since the iOS device doesn't care, for the most part, where the WiFi is coming from:

> [PC] --->--(WiFi)--->--> [iOS Device]

So, you might consider grabbing a wireless card for your PC. Alternatively, a jailbroken iPhone might be able to get more mileage with a  USB cable than a vanilla one would.

Comment: It looks like the USB and Bluetooth routes work today, through Settings -> Mobile Data -> Personal Hotspot

Comment: @Andomar, Personal hotspot is iOS internet connection to other device - not what the asker is asking.

Comment: @Moshe, please describe the process.

Comment: Linked article works for macOS sharing macbook wifi to iPhone over USB! https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb

Answer (score 2):

With the standard iOS Version: **NO**

*But* if your iPhone is jailbroken, this may/could work for you: [Use PC Internet over IPhone via USB Cable](http://forums.imore.com/jailbreaking-unlocking-hacks-themes-mods/232233-use-pc-internet-over-iphone-via-usb-cable.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s how to set up a pc to work like a Mac for this:

- [Can I share my iMac's internet to iPhone or iPad over USB?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb)?

  1. plug laptop to ethernet cable (has internet)
  2. create adhoc wireless network on laptop, call it mylaptop, give it open or wep security. (wpa2 doesn't work on iphone)
  3. connect iphone via wifi settings
  4. go into control panel->Network and Internet->Network Connections, and click on Local Area Connection AND multi select  Wireless Network Connection,  right click.
  5. right click and select BRIDGE connections.

YAY it works.. AND all broadcasts on your internal network are also bridged out to your phone, so if you have apps like me that use UDP broadcast.. they still work too. just like real.