# Share PC's internet to iPad through USB

Tags: network, usb, internet-sharing

I am trying to get my iPad an internet connection through a USB cable from my PC, which does not have a wifi card, so I cannot make any hotspots. I have searched a lot for a solution to this and have not found what I want, I was able to hack together a macOS virtual machine, so I can use [this MacOS feature](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-internet-connection-mac-network-users-mchlp1540/mac) which has worked, but running a virtual machine while trying to do other heavy tasks does not work well on my machine.

I have also found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39807/share-internet-connection-from-a-pc-to-an-iphone-through-the-usb-cable) post, which is asking the same thing I am, but it has almost been 5 years since it has had activity and the only solution it explains is to use wifi hotspots which I can't do.

Another post I found explaining how to do this on macOS had an [interesting comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb#comment437944_284442) that explained an alternate way to do this, but I can't piece together what they are explaining or how to do it on windows, not macOS.

Lastly, I want to say that I've had the VM crash on me once before, but the internet connection from my PC to the iPad still worked without the VM running (although some VM processes were still running on the pc in task manager), I have not been able to reproduce this, but I might spend more time trying to.

**Specs:** iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) with 15.3.1, Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Comment: Probably because installing a bridge happens on the router.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I don't use Windows much but my understanding is that it should be possible, check https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-windows-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable/119324#119324 (this answer is about Android, but at the end of the post you will see how to configure the network interface that is created when you plug in your iPad to use Internet sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately, there is no new network interface created when you plug in an i device unless you turn on a personal hotspot which I do not have on my iPad.